# How do I pass a var from one viewModel to a new viewModel in my .fullScreenCover() View?

Tags: swift, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm building an app with swiftUI & firebase/firestore. I open a fullscreenCover sheet of a product selected from a catalog and the user can add it to a list below it. The product is selected on the previous page, and that is passed onto the .fullScreeenCover, where I'm introducing a new ViewModel for the list.

**Where I'm getting confused:** How do I pass the product ID passed into this fullScreenCover view into my newly introduced list's viewModel so that I can run the "add to list" function?

**ViewModel for my List:**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let var product: Product 
    @Published var userList = [List]()
    @Published var list: List
    
    init(list: List) {
        self.list = list
    }
    
    func fetchList() {
        let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("List")
        guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
        
        docRef.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.userList = documents.map({ List(dictionary: $0.data())} )}
    }
    
    func AddProductToList(product: Product, list: List) {
        
        let listRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("List").document(list.id).collection("Products")
        let productRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Products").document(product.id)
        
        productRef.getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            listRef.document(self.product.id).setData([:]) { _ in
                print("\(self.product.title) was saved to \(self.list.name)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for .fullScreenCover() sheet View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListCoverView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let viewModel: LikeViewModel
    @StateObject var listViewModel = ListViewModel(list)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            VStack (spacing: 10) {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: viewModel.product.image))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 220)
                        .padding(.top,10)
                    
                    Text("\(viewModel.product.title)")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    Text(viewModel.product.company)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    
                    // Fetch products
                    
                    listViewModel.fetchList()
                    
                })
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        Button(action: listViewModel.AddProductToList(Product)) {
                            ForEach(listViewModel.userList){list in
                                ListRow(list: listViewModel.list, viewModel: listViewModel)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
                }
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {isPresented.toggle()}, label : {
            
            Text("Close")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        })
        .padding()
    }   
}
```

**Parent View of the .fullScreenCover()**

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let product: Product
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LikeViewModel
    @State private var isShowingNewListSheet = false
    
    init(product: Product) {
        self.product = product
        self.viewModel = LikeViewModel(product: product)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
            
            WebImage(url: URL(string: product.image))
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        
            Text(product.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        
            Text(product.company)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding(.trailing,65)
                
                
            HStack{
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                viewModel.didLike ? viewModel.UnlikeProduct() : viewModel.LikeProduct()

                }, label : {
                    
                Image(systemName: viewModel.didLike ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(viewModel.didLike ? .red : .black)

            })
            .padding(.trailing,5)
        
            
            Button(action: { isShowingNewListSheet.toggle()
                
            }, label : {
                
                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                })
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingNewListSheet) {
                    ListCoverView(isPresented: $isShowingNewListSheet, viewModel: viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom)
        .background(Color(.white))
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code for the parent view?

Comment: To many missed dependent components. Could you focus on short snapshot of what, from where, to where, should be passed?

Comment: @Asperi simply stated, is there a way to introduce a new Model in a fullScreenCover without having to reference it in the parent screens. I have my lists appearing for the first time in the modal, but xcode is forcing me to add it in the parent views. there must be a way to use the new model/viewmodel without having to mention it in the parent?